# SQLiteDatabase being closed before test can run

Tags: android, database, unit-testing, junit, android-sqlite

I have an issue where my database handle is being closed during my test and I am not sure why.

The `@Before` method runs correctly, but the `@Test` method throws an exception : *attempt to re-open an already-closed object*. I am not closing it anywhere in my code, so I am not sure how it is getting closed.

The method marked with `@Test` is the only one in the test so far, so no other tests are running before it.

Can anyone help me understand what is happening here?

**Test**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class DatabaseTest {

    private Database subject;
    private SQLiteDatabase wDB;

    public DatabaseTest(){

        DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
        subject = new Database(helper);
        wDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    }


    // remove any preexisting records from the database 
    @Before
    public void cleanSlate(){
        wDB.delete(Database.ITEMS_TABLE, null, null);
    }


    @Test
    public void testInsert(){

        Cursor c;
        Item i = getMockItem();
        subject.update(i);

        // (per below) DatabaseTest.java:46: 
        c = wDB.query(Database.ITEM_TABLE,Database.ALL_COLUMNS,null,null,null,null,null);

        //...
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.example.app.debug/databases/storage.db
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
at com.example.app.data.local.DatabaseTest.testInsert(DatabaseTest.java:46)
```

**Update Method**

```
public void update(Item item){

        SQLiteDatabase wDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues cv = entryToContentValues(item);
        wDB.insertWithOnConflict(ITEM_TABLE, null, cv, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE );

        wDB.close();
    }
```

Comment: You may have to show the code for `getMockItem()` and/or `subject.update(i)`. Do either close the database? If so then that would be the likely cause. You could try including `wDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();` just before line 46.

Comment: @MikeT The update method does call close() (Source was added to the question), but it does so on it's own instance of SQLiteDatabase. Does close() apply globally?

Comment: In short basically yes.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are closing the database in the `update` method and thus the database is closed when trying to run the query at line 46.

One solution would be to not close the database in the update method. However you should then close it when finished with the database.

Another solution could be to call `getWriteableDatabase();` before the query but after the `update`.

Other solutions could range up to having a singleton thus ensuring that you only have a single instance/connection and then only closing the database when the App is destroyed (I'm using this approach in the app I am using).

P.S. you should also close cursors then they are finished with as they can cause *Too many Open errors/issues*. Personally I tend to put cursor closing into the activities `onDestroy` method.